# The value of parameter $a$ for which $\dfrac{ax^2+3x-4}{a+3x-4x^2}$ takes all real values for $x\in R$ are:

Tags: functions, quadratics

=> The value of parameter $a$ for which $\dfrac{ax^2+3x-4}{a+3x-4x^2}$

> takes all real values for $x\in R$ are:

My question is why we need to validate end points i.e. $1,7$ (Refer the last part of my attempt)

My attempt is as follows:-

$$y=\dfrac{ax^2+3x-4}{a+3x-4x^2}$$

$$ya+3yx-4yx^2=ax^2+3x-4$$
$$x^2(-4y-a)+x(3y-3)+ya+4=0$$

As $x$ can be any real, so $D\ge0$

$$9y^2+9-18y-4(ya+4)(-4y-a)\ge0$$
$$9y^2+9-18y+4(4y^2a+ya^2+16y+4a)\ge0$$
$$y^2(9+16a)+y(4a^2+64-18)+9+16a\ge0$$
$$y^2(9+16a)+y(4a^2+46)+9+16a\ge0$$

As range is $R$, so discriminant of quadratic in $y$ should be less than equal to zero

$$4(2a^2+23)^2-4(9+16a)^2\le0$$
$$(2a^2+23-9-16a)(2a^2+23+9+16a)\le0$$
$$(2a^2-16a+14)(2a^2+16a+32)\le0$$
$$(a^2-8a+7)(a^2+8a+16)\le0$$
$$a\in[1,7]$$

But in such type of questions, we always check at endpoints like here we need to check at $a=1$ and $a=7$. But I don't understand what is so special about endpoints.

From the above calculation I can only say at $a=1,7$ discriminant of quadratic in $y$ is zero, but what is so special about this. Please help me in this.

Comment: Does the question say the function has to defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ in addition to taking on all real values?

Comment: no, its not for all $x$, its just $x\in R$

Comment: The reason is because for $$D=(9+16a)y^2+(4a^2+46)y+(9+16a)\ge 0$$ for all $y$ we need the value of the coefficient before $y^2$ to be strictly greater than zero. This would make the determinant strictly negative and we would have $4(2a^2+23)^2-4(9+16a)^2< 0 \implies a\in(1,7)$.

Comment: I tried to answer a similar question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3870052/find-the-limits-between-which-a-must-lie-in-order-that-fracax2-7x55x2/3893956#3893956

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> why at only endpoints {1,7} numerator and denominator are having common roots

Let $x=X$ be a common root. Then, we have $a+3X-4X^2=0$ and $aX^2+3X-4=0$. Subtracting the latter from the former gives $(a+4)(1-X^2)=0$. If $a=-4$, then $\dfrac{ax^2+3x-4}{a+3x-4x^2}=1$, so we have $a\not=-4$ from which $X=\pm 1$ follows. For $X=1$, we get $a=1$. For $X=-1$, we get $a=7$.

> what is so special about these endpoints.

We see that $(1)$ is equivalent to $(2)$ where

$(1)$ For every $y$, there exists at least one $x$ such that $y=\dfrac{ax^2+3x-4}{a+3x-4x^2}$.

$(2)$ For every $y$, there exists at least one $x$ such that $(-4y-a)x^2+(3y-3)x+ya+4=0$ $\color{red}{\text{and}\ a+3x-4x^2\not=0}$.

(The red part is important. It seems that you are thinking that $(1)$ is equivalent to $(3)$, but note that $(3)$ is not equivalent to $(1)$ where

$(3)$ For every $y$, there exists at least one $x$ such that $(-4y-a)x^2+(3y-3)x+ya+4=0$.)

Here, let us take $y=-\frac a4$ **for which the coefficient of $x^2$ is zero**. Then, $(-4y-a)x^2+(3y-3)x+ya+4=0$ becomes $(a+4)(3x+a-4)=0$. Since $a\not=-4$, it follows from $x=\frac{4-a}{3}$ and $a+3x-4x^2\not=0$ that $a\not=1$ and $a\not=7$.

So, "$a\not=1$ and $a\not=7$" is a necessary condition.

If $a\not=1$ and $a\not=7$, then we have not only that the coefficient of $x^2$ is not zero, but also that the numerator and the denominator don't have any common root.  So, we see that $x$ satisfying $y(a+3x-4x^2)=ax^2+3x-4$ also satisfies $a+3x-4x^2\not=0$ for every $y$, and that $(2)$ is equivalent to $(3)$ under the condition that $a\not=1$ and $a\not=7$.

In conclusion, under the condition that $a\not=1$ and $a\not=7$, we can consider $D$ safely as you did.

---

**Added** :

> if you explain this solution to anybody, then how will you do it. First you will calculate the interval of a which will come out [1,7],

**No, I will not.**

Considering $D\ge 0$ first is **wrong** because it is possible that $(-4y-a)x^2+(3y-3)x+ya+4=0$ is **not** a quadratic equation.

You cannot consider $D$ when the above equation is not a quadratic equation.

You have to deal with the case where the equation is not a quadratic equation first and separately, and then consider $D$.

---

In the following, I'm going to write my solution to the question with some comments which should be helpful to understand why I take the step.

*My solution* :

We want to find $a$ such that for every $y$, there exists at least one $x$ satisfying $y=\dfrac{ax^2+3x-4}{a+3x-4x^2}$.

So, we want to find $a$ such that for every $y$, there exists at least one $x$ satisfying $y(a+3x-4x^2)=ax^2+3x-4$ and $a+3x-4x^2\not=0$.

[comments : This is an important step. Note that there is an additional condition $a+3x-4x^2\not=0$. This moment is not the time to consider $D\ge 0$. Before considering $D$, we have two points to consider. The first point is to consider the case where $y(a+3x-4x^2)=ax^2+3x-4$, i.e. $(-4y-a)x^2+(3y-3)x+ya+4=0$ is not a quadratic equation because you cannot consider $D$ when the equation is not a quadratic equation.]

Let us take $y=-\frac a4$ for which the equation is not a quadratic equation. Then, $(-4y-a)x^2+(3y-3)x+ya+4=0$ becomes $(a+4)(3x+a-4)=0$. Since $a\not=-4$, we get $x=\frac{4-a}{3}$, and so setting it into $a+3x-4x^2\not=0$ gives $$a+3\cdot\frac{4-a}{3}-4\bigg(\frac{4-a}{3}\bigg)^2\not=0\iff a\not=1\quad\text{and}\quad a\not=7$$

So, "$a\not=1$ and $a\not=7$" is a necessary condition.

[comments : The second point is to consider the part "$y(a+3x-4x^2)=ax^2+3x-4$ and $a+3x-4x^2\not=0$". We want to remove the part "and $a+3x-4x^2\not=0$". To do this, we want to find all $a$ such that $a+3x-4x^2$ and $ax^2+3x-4$ have a common root.]

Let $x=X$ be a common root of $a+3x-4x^2$ and $ax^2+3x-4$. Then, we have $a+3X-4X^2=0$ and $aX^2+3X-4=0$. Subtracting the latter from the former gives $(a+4)(1-X^2)=0$. If $a=-4$, then $\dfrac{ax^2+3x-4}{a+3x-4x^2}=1$, so we have $a\not=-4$ from which $X=\pm 1$ follows. For $X=1$, we get $a=1$. For $X=-1$, we get $a=7$.

So, we see that if $a\not=1$ and $a\not=7$, then $a+3x-4x^2$ and $ax^2+3x-4$ do not have any common root. From this, we see that if $a\not=1$ and $a\not=7$, then $x$ satisfying $y(a+3x-4x^2)=ax^2+3x-4$ also satisfies $a+3x-4x^2\not=0$ for every $y$.

This means that under the condition that $a\not=1$ and $a\not=7$, all we need is to find $a$ such that for every $y$, there exists at least one $x$ satisfying $(-4y-a)x^2+(3y-3)x+ya+4=0$.

[comments : Now, it is time to consider $D\ge 0$ because under the condition that $a\not=1$ and $a\not=7$, the equation is a quadratic equation, and also the additional condition "and $a+3x-4x^2\not=0$" is already removed. Now, you can consider $D$ safely.]

Considering $D\ge 0$, i.e.$$y^2(9+16a)+y(4a^2+46)+9+16a\ge0$$

we want to find $a$ such that this is true for every $y$. So, we have
$$9+16a\gt 0\qquad\text{and}\qquad (4a^2+46)^2-4(9+16a)^2\le 0,$$
i.e.
$$1\le a\le 7$$

With the condition that $a\not=1$ and $a\not=7$, the answer is $$\color{red}{1\lt a\lt 7}$$

Comment: I just want to know this: We are getting common roots in numerator and denominator at $a=1,7$ and the range of $a$ we found in the last part of the question is $[1,7]$. So is it the coincidence that we are getting common roots at endpoints of an interval or is there any logic that in such case we will get common roots only at the endpoints of interval of $a$.

Comment: Reason why I am asking that is that if you explain this solution to anybody, then how will you do it. First you will calculate the interval of $a$ which will come out $[1,7]$, now the hard point begins. How will one know that at what values of $a$ one should check for condition of common roots. Can't there be any value of $a\in (1,7)$ where we have condition of common roots?

Comment: @user3290550: Your comments are based on the idea that $D\ge 0$ is the very first step. I would say No. Considering $D\ge 0$ first is **wrong** because it is possible that $(-4y-a)x^2+(3y-3)x+ya+4=0$ is **not** a quadratic equation. You have to deal with the case where the equation is not a quadratic equation first and separately. See the added part where I showed my solution.

Comment: By the condition of common roots, we got $a\ne 1, a\ne 7$. Besides that by making the coefficient of $x^2$ zero , finding the equation of $x$ and then putting it in $a+3x-4x^2\ne 0$, from there also we got $a\ne 1, a\ne 7$. So both of these steps are giving same results, is this coincidence or do we need to perform only one step?

Answer (score 1):

When $a=1$, $\displaystyle y=\frac{x^2+3x-4}{1+3x-4x^2}=\frac{-x-4}{1+4x}\ne-\dfrac14$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

When $a=7$, $\displaystyle y=\frac{7x^2+3x-4}{7+3x-4x^2}=\frac{7x-4}{7-4x}\ne-\dfrac74$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: yeah that's what my question is, why it happening specially at $a=1,7$ and not at some other value of a.

Comment: ask yourself the reason, why did you check only at $a=1,7$, why not for other values of $a$

Answer (score 0):

The value of parameter $a$ for which $\dfrac{ax^2+3x-4}{a+3x-4x^2}$ takes all real values for $x\in R$

$\dfrac{ax^2+3x-4}{a+3x-4x^2}$ will take all the values for $x \in \mathbb R$ only if the denominator is not equal to zero!

So, For $a + 3x - 4x^2 \neq 0; \iff -3 \pm \sqrt{9 +16a} \neq 0$

We need to check all the points for which the denominator will become equal to zero, and we need to remove those values of $a$ which includes $1, 7$.

Comment: actually if you read the full question, I have solved it already , I am just asking why we need to check at endpoints?

Comment: @user3290550 endpoints?

Comment: I got answer as $a\in[1,7]$ so by endpoints I mean $a=1,7$

Comment: @user3290550 At endpoints, the denominator of fraction *may become equal to zero* for some particular value of $x$. This is I guess what you mean...

Comment: denominator is not getting zero at $a=1,7$. Check it.

Comment: At $a=1,7$, function gets converted into the form $\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}$

Comment: For a=1. x = 1 to get denominator = 0 and for a= 7, x = -1 to get denominator = 0

Comment: @user3290550 We are not actually concerned about that, we are *only* concerned about the denominator, otherwise the fraction is always defined!

Comment: ok tell me,  what is your final answer to the above question.

Comment: see the answer.

Comment: @user3290550 I guess you are confused with something I don't understand, if you don't mind asking me repeated question, I may help you... :)

Comment: @user3290550 If you don't mind, I've edited the question a bit to help you more :)

Comment: actually its not about denominator getting zero, I think you would have got that.

Comment: @user3290550 Sincere Apologies, I still don't get... Are you trying to find why 0 Discriminant is related to Denominator of fraction? or something else...

Comment: see  in this question we have to find the possible values of 'a' for which range of function is $R$. Is there any doubt in this?

Comment: okay, no doubt here.

Comment: so by the process which I did in the question, I got $a\in [1,7]$. Any doubt in this? Please note its $a$, not $x$

Comment: Apologies, I'd have to go, I'll look your explanation later, just post it.

Comment: now if you put $a=1$ or $a=7$, something special happens, denominator gets factorized and its one factor gets cancelled out with one factor in numerator. Any doubt in this? If not then write and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote $f(x)=ax^2+3x−4$, $g(x)=-4x^2+3x+a$, and $h(x)=f(x)/g(x)$.

Since $a>0>-9/16>-4$, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ cannot have the same roots, and each of them has two distinct roots. However, they may have a common root. If $a=1,7$ then there exists $y_0\in \mathbb{\mathbb{R}}$ for which only one $x$ may give $h(x)=y_0$. This $x$ may be the root of the denominator, so we must check. Else, when $1<a<7$, there exists two distinct candidates $x_1,x_2$ which may give $h(x)=y$. In this case at least one of $x_1,x_2$ is not a root for $g$, since otherwise they will be the roots of $f$.

Comment: how do you know that when $a=1,a=7$ , $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ will have a common root.

Comment: how can you ascertain that for other values of $1<a<7$ , there will not be any common root of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Comment: I don't know in advance that they will have a common root in $a=1,7$. But when each of a quadratic functions $f$ and $g$ has a root, we know that $f$ and $g$ have the same sets of roots iff $f=b \cdot g$ for some non-zero constant $b$ (exercise). In your case, $f$ cannot be a multiple of $g$ by a constant, so we are sure that $f$ and $g$ have at most one common root. Thus, at least one of $x_1,x_2$ in the answer above, will be in the domain of $h$ such that $h(x)=y$.