# Find the sum of maximum value of $x_1$ and minimum value of $x_2$ for the following given data.

Tags: optimization, logarithms, roots, quadratics, maxima-minima

Consider the equation $(\log_2 x)^2-4\log_2x-(m^2+2m+13)=0$. Let the real roots of the equation be $x_1,x_2$ such that $x_1<x_2$. Find the sum of maximum value of $x_1$ and minimum value of $x_2$

My attempt is as follows:-

For minimizing $x_2-x_1$, we need to minimize $x_2$ and maximize $x_1$ and I think vice-versa should also be true.

Let $u=x_2-x_1$ and assume $y=\log_2 x$, so equation would look like $y^2-4y-(m^2+2m+13)=0$

$$y_1+y_2=4$$
$$y_1y_2=-(m^2+2m+13)$$

$$u=x_2-x_1=2^{y_2}-2^{y_1}$$

$$u=2^{y_2}-2^{4-y_2}$$

$$\dfrac{du}{d{y_2}}=2^{y_2}\log 2+2^{4-y_2}\log2$$

$$2^{y_2}+\dfrac{16}{2^{y_2}}=0$$

But its not taking me anywhere.

Any suggestions or inputs? Actual answer is $\dfrac{257}{4}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x_2=2^{2+\sqrt{m^2+2m+17}}=2^{2+\sqrt{(m+1)^2+16}}\geq2^{2+4}=64.$$
$$x_1=2^{2-\sqrt{m^2+2m+17}}=2^{2-\sqrt{(m+1)^2+16}}\leq2^{2-4}=\frac{1}{4}.$$
The equality in the both cases occurs for $m=-1$, which gives the answer: $64\frac{1}{4}.$

Comment: I missed the very simple thing, thanks. If you don't mind, I also wanted your input on this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585702/the-value-of-parameter-a-for-which-dfracax23x-4a3x-4x2-takes-all-re/3585898#3585898