# The largest interval for which $x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1>0$

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, quadratics

The largest interval for which $x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1>0$

A) $-4<x<0$, B) $0<x<1$, C)$-100<x<100$, D) $-\infty<x<\infty$

My attempt is as follows:-

As coefficient of $x^{12}$ is positive, so given polynomial will be positive for $x\in(-\infty,a)\cup(b,c)\cdots\cdots (\lambda,\infty)$

This is just the rough estimation of set of values of $x$ for which polynomial can be positive.

But If we talk of largest interval, then it can happen that for all $x$ polynomial is positive, so in that case $-\infty<x<\infty$. But is this the correct approach because I am doubtful if the given polynomial can be factorized or not.

Comment: @BrianTung My comment was wrong; I misread a sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x\leq0$ it's obvious.

For $0<x\leq1$ we have:
$$x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1=1-x+x^4(1-x^5)+x^{12}>0$$ and for $x>1$ we obtain:

$$x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1=x^9(x^3-1)+x(x^3-1)+1>0.$$
Id est, the answer is D).

Comment: I posted a question 4-5 days ago but didn't get any satisfactory answer, please help me in this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585702/the-value-of-parameter-a-for-which-dfracax23x-4a3x-4x2-takes-all-re/3585724?noredirect=1#comment7372046_3585724

Answer (score 1):

You can study the inequality: $$x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x>0$$ which is very simple. If we find that this inequality holds $\forall x \in R$ we have done. In other case, we have to compute some values of $x$ for which $f(x)<0$ and then detrmine whether $f(x)+1>0$ or $f(x)+1<0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that for $x=0$ the polynomial is positive, and hence it is positive on an open neighbourhood of $1$. This eliminates options A and B. It is also clear that $-100$ and $100$ are not zeros of the polynomial, excluding option C.

Alternatively, for negative $x$ the polynomial is positive. Then it can only be option D.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer:** For $x<0$ all terms are positive, so the inequality is obeyed. Then it's option D.

**Full answer**

For $x\le 0$ all terms are non-negative, so the inequality is obeyed. For $x\ge 1$ we have $x^{12}\ge x^8$ and $x^4\ge x$, so once again all $x$ are good. What's left is $x\in(0,1)$. For that:$$x^12-x^8+x^4-x+1=x^9(x^3-1)+x(x^3-1)+1=x(x^8+1)(x^3-1)+1$$
We know that $x^8+1$ is going to be in the interval $(1,2)$, and since $x^3-1$ is negative, we can just replace $x^8+1$ with $2$. If it works for this value, then all is fine.

So what's left is to calculate the minimum value of $x^4-x$:
$$(x^4-x)'=4x^3-1=0$$
$$x_{MIN}=\frac 1{\sqrt[3]4}$$
Then $$x(x^3-1)|_{MIN}=-\frac 1{\sqrt[3]4}\frac 34$$
We multiply with the maximum value for $x^8+1$, which is $2$.
The inequality is now $$1-\frac1{\sqrt[3]4}\frac 32>0$$Move the negative term to the right and cube:
$$1\gt \frac{3^3}{4\cdot 2^3}=\frac{27}{32}$$
This is a true statement, so , when putting everything together we get that the inequality is obeyed for any $x\in\mathbb R$

Comment: but for positive $x$, how can we say that polynomial is always positive.

Comment: I will add it to my answer

Comment: for $x>1$ it is fine, but how we can say in the interval $x\in(0,1)$

Comment: add it only for $x\in(0,1)$ because there only polynomial can be negative

Comment: @user3290550 :  You do not have to understand the behaviour for *any* $x > 0$.  The argument here shows that there is at least one infinitely large interval on which the polynomial is positive.  There is no larger interval than infinitely large.  Consequently, none of the answers with only finitely large intervals can be "The largest interval".

Comment: @user3290550 I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The sequence [image]

is a Sturm sequence for your polynomial. Their limits to $+\infty$ have signs $+,-,-,+,+,+,+,-,-,+$, which has $4$ sign changes. Their limits to $-\infty$ have signs $+,+,+,+,-,+,-,-,+,+$, which has also $4$ sign changes. Therefore, there are no real roots of that polynomial. Since its value at $x=0$ is $1$, which is positive, then all its values on the reals are positive too.

Computed with [this calculator](https://planetcalc.com/7719/).

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1.$

Let $x>1$, then $$f(x)= x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1=x^9(x^3-1)+x(x^3-1)+1>1$$
$$\implies f(x) > 1$$
Next let $x<1$, then $$f(x)=x^{12}+x^4(1-x^5)+(1-x)>0.$$
$$\implies f(x)>0$$
Let $x=0$, then $f(0)=1.$
Hence $f(x) > 0, \forall x \in (-\infty,\infty)$