# Can this be an onto function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, quadratics, quadratic-forms

> A function $f:R\to R$, where $R$ is set of real numbers, is defined by $$f(x)=\frac{\alpha x^2 + 6x - 8}{\alpha + 6x -8x^2}$$
> Find the interval of values of $\alpha$ for which $f$ is onto. Justify your answer.

My attempt:

Since the domain is all real values, the denominator in $f(x)$ must have no real roots, so discriminant of the quadratic (denominator) is less than zero :

$$9 + 8\alpha <0 {\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}..(1)$$

But then I noticed that the expression for discriminant is the same for both numerator and denominator, if $(1)$ is true, numerator will also have no real roots which means there is no $x∈R$ such that $f(x)=0$   $\\\\\\$ and so $f(x)$ can never be onto for any value of $\alpha$

Textbook Solution:

The expression can be written as (Note: $f(x)=y$):
$$ (8y+\alpha)x^2 + 6(1-y)x-(8+\alpha y)=0{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}..(1)$$

Since $x$ is real, $D\ge0$:

$$(8\alpha +9)y^2 + (46 + {\alpha}^2)y + (8\alpha + 9)\ge 0{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}{\space}..(2)$$

For $y$ to be real, $9+8\alpha\gt0$ and $(46+{\alpha}^2)^2-4(9+8\alpha)^2\le0$

Solving these inequalities, we get $2\le\alpha\le14$

I've looked for solutions online but they all give the textbook answer which led me to believe that maybe I was doing something wrong. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is poorly worded. They do not want the domain to be the set of real numbers, they want it to be $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \alpha + 6x - 8x^2 \neq 0\}$.

In calculus and analysis it's common for functions not to be defined everywhere and many times the phrase "real valued function" means the domain is an appropriate subset of the real numbers. The proper term for this is a "partial function" but since these are so common in this area of mathematics, it's common to just call these "functions."

Whether it's still appropriate to write "$f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$" I would argue no. I've always seen $f : D \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $D$ is an unspecified set but is assumed to be the largest subset of $\mathbb{R}$ for which the definition of $f$ makes sense. It would seem that whoever wrote this textbook have a different opinion than me.

I would add: while I think it's appropriate for a calculus book to be a bit sloppy about domains, if this were a book on elementary set theory/logic/basic proofs, then being this sloppy is wholly inappropriate.

Comment: This is from a high school textbook. The chapter is relations and functions. The part about it being poorly worded, It's just that I have noticed that they always mention precise domains while defining function, maybe it went wrong this once. Also, shouldn't $9+8\alpha$ be $<0$ (see my attempt) contrary to the solution where it's $>0$ ?

Comment: @Physicsa Yes, it should be $9 + 8\alpha < 0$. It's also possible that when they wrote this problem they made that mistake with the discriminant and therefore didn't realize that if $2 \le \alpha \le 14$ then the denominator can be $0$.

Comment: Hey, I found some similar questions here, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585702/the-value-of-parameter-a-for-which-dfracax23x-4a3x-4x2-takes-all-re?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3870052/find-the-limits-between-which-a-must-lie-in-order-that-fracax2-7x55x2/3893956#3893956   and in both of these, while solving, they have discriminant of denominator >0 , maybe they didn't notice, so aren't all of these incorrect too ?

Comment: @Physicsa Well there are 3 quadratics in these questions. You have the quadratic in the numerator, the quadratic in the denominator, and the quadratic you get when you try to solve $y = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ for $x$ in terms of $y$. To be *onto* we are asking for $y = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ to have a solution for every $y$ and so this discriminant needs to be $\ge 0$. But of course, if you're asking for $g(x) \neq 0$ then you want the discriminant of $g$ to be negative—this is a different discriminant.

Comment: Now as it turns out, we do want $g(x)$ to equal $0$ sometimes or else it won't be onto. For instance $\frac{1}{1 + x^2}$ isn't onto because $1 + x^2$ is always $\ge 1$ and so $\frac1{1 + x^2}$ is always $\leq 1$.

Comment: Agreed, allowing $g(x)=0$ will make $y$ onto but assuming that here (my question), they want domain to be precisely $R$ , then my answer would be correct, right ?

Comment: @Physicsa Yes, if you want the domain to be all of $\mathbb{R}$ then yes, the discriminant (of the denominator) should be $< 0$.